# How to fetch an exception message and then send an HTML email containing that exception error

Tags: python, email

How can I pass the exception from test_file1 below to test_file2 so that it can send an e-mail with that exception information?

**test_file1.py**

```
    import sys
    try:
        print(5/0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
```

Output:

> integer division or modulo by zero 
> Error on line 15

**test_file2.py**

```
import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    me = "my@email.com"
    you = "your@email.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Link"
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = you
    
    text = "Exception mail"
    html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
    
        <b> Exception Details: </b>print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
        <b>
            Error on line {}.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno)
        </b>
        
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    
    mail.starttls()
    
    mail.login('userName', 'password')
    mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()
```

So basically the exception message from file1.py should be pass to file2.py for sending mail with that error message as:

```
>> Exception Details: integer division or modulo by zero
>> Found Exception!
>> Error on line 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use a function in your `test_file2.py` then simply import and use it in `test_file1.py`. Note I used a formatted string by adding `f` to your html string so I could use variables in the string.

**test_file2.py:**

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def send_error_email(exception, message):
    me = "my@email.com"
    you = "your@email.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Link"
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = you

    text = "Exception mail"
    html = f"""
        <html>
          <body>
    
            <b> Exception Details: </b> Exception: {exception}
            <b>
                {message}
            </b>
    
          </body>
        </html>
        """

    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()

    mail.starttls()

    mail.login('userName', 'password')
    mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()
```

**test_file1.py:**

```py
import sys
from test_file2 import send_error_email

try:
    print(5 / 0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
    send_error_email(exception=e, message='Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
```

**EDIT:** If you want more details, you can use the `traceback` package:

```
import traceback
from test_file2 import send_error_email

try:
    print(5 / 0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    message=f'Error on line {traceback.format_exc()}'
    print(message)
    send_error_email(exception=e, message=message)
```

**EDIT #2:**
To use older `.format()` for string, you can pass in the arguments

```
html = """
        <html>
          <body>

            <b> Exception Details: </b> Exception: {exception}
            <b>
                {message}
            </b>

          </body>
        </html>
        """.format(exception=exception, message=message)
```

Comment: How to get file path name where this exception occurred as a additional message in email so it will be easy to navigate and fix that error. @krchun

Comment: @Ansh You would want to use the `traceback` package. I updated the answer to include an example :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , one doubt ......

html = f"""
        <html>
          <body>

................how to use f-string in case of python-2. in this case   @krchun

Comment: @Ansh Just updated the answer with the `html` variable using the `.format()` function :) You would simply pass the variables/arguments into the function

Comment: When I try to run this code in Jupyter Notebook with a simple test case the code runs forever and I have to stop the kernel. Any tips?